# get local image and store to amazon and store link in db

Tags: amazon-s3, jscript

i have a web page which allows user to choose image file from local disk..what i want to do is that get image store it on amazon s 3 bucket and convert local link to amazon link and store it in my db.how do i do this.also please tell, is amazon for free and how to make bucket...please help i am a complete newbie to amazon.
here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selection1.css">
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script>
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
{
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) 
{
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(300)
                    .height(300);

 };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }



 }
</script>

</head>

<body><center>

<div id="div1">
<h2>Select 3 images as your password by clicking the 'choose' button and then click 'submit' button to proceed furthur.</h2>
<div id="div2">
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div id="div3">
<img id="" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div id="div4">
<img id="" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
</br></br>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<input type='file'  />
<input type='file'  />
</div>

</center></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding pricing

> As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3
>   for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3
>   standard storage, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, and 15GB of
>   data transfer out each month for one year.

This is from their official site,
For creating buckets and uploading images.. Please go through their documentation ,they are pretty clear and elaborate.You can either use REST API'S to send request or make use of their SDK's in various languages(PHP,.NET etc)
Please refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/MakingRequests.html